# How do I run a multi-line powershell script from excel vba as a single line?

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

Powershell:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Excel VBA:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run ("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -executionpolicy bypass -command ""line1; line2; lin3; line4"")
```

`line1` will run and open a powershell window but the rest of the commands do not run. I can copy and paste each of `line2`, `line3` and `line4` individually into the powershell window at the prompt and they will each run.

Comment: Note:  There is a end parenthesis ")" at the end of the VBA command

Comment: Use `-EncodedCommand`.  See: `powershell.exe -?`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using powershell's `-EncodedCommand` parameter.

From their help documentation (`powershell -?`):

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

To generate the base64 for the parameter (shortened):

```
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String(
    [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(@'
line1
line2
line3
line4
'@)
)
```

In action:

```
powershell -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -EncodedCommand "bABpAG4AZQAxAA0ACgBsAGkAbgBlADIADQAKAGwAaQBuAGUAMwANAAoAbABpAG4AZQA0AA=="
```

*Note: This will fail with `'line1' is not recognized` since I took your example literally.*