# How can i run multiple replace commands from one line of batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have minimum to none knowledge of powershell :(

Hi I have two possible options to replace text from an .ini file, one is a menu-style batch, where choosing an option will execute a command.

My problem is: if I use the batch code I can only change a known resolution, because I don't know how to add multiple replace actions so they work if one fails.

The Powershell code does executes MULTIPLE replace commands, but I don't know how to edit it to use it as a batch command (`powershell -command` etc.)

Thank you in advance :)

Batch script:

```
@echo off
set ffile='resolutions.ini'
set HDReady='/resolution:1280,720'
set FullHD='/resolution:1920,1080'
set QuadHD='/resolution:2560,1440'
set UltraHD='/resolution:3840,2160'
powershell -Command "(gc %ffile%) -replace %hdready%, %fullhd% | Out-File %ffile% -encoding utf8"
```

Powershell script:

```
$original_file = 'path\resolutions.ini'
$destination_file =  'path\resolutions.ini'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '/resolution:1280,720', '/resolution:1920,1080' `
       -replace '/resolution:2560,1440', '/resolution:1920,1080' `
       -replace '/resolution:3840,2160', '/resolution:1920,1080' 
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

Comment: If you want it to be on one line, you can separate commands with a semicolon `;`

Comment: Hi @TheIncorrigible1, as I stated I have barely minimum to none knowledge, Where do I place the semicolon? How the code looks like? 
I tried but the cmd closes and the resolution isn't changed in the ini file:

powershell -Command "(gc %ffile%) -replace %HDReady%, %fullhd%; -replace %QuadHD%, %fullhd% | Out-File %ffile% -encoding utf8"

Comment: [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138057/how-do-i-run-a-multi-line-powershell-script-from-excel-vba-as-a-single-line/51139909#51139909) on a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: I've seen your solution, care to explain it?

Comment: I tried to switch the text between the "bABpAG4AZ..." with my command between the "". After running the script, nothing happened inside the .ini. I repeat, I have very poor knowledge of powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is one (1) line what you really want?

```
(Get-Content 'path\resolutions.ini') | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '/resolution:1280,720', '/resolution:1920,1080' -replace '/resolution:2560,1440', '/resolution:1920,1080' -replace '/resolution:3840,2160', '/resolution:1920,1080'} | Set-Content 'path\resolutions.ini'
```

or

```
$original_file = 'path\resolutions.ini'; $destination_file = 'path\resolutions.ini'; (Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '/resolution:1280,720', '/resolution:1920,1080' -replace '/resolution:2560,1440', '/resolution:1920,1080' -replace '/resolution:3840,2160', '/resolution:1920,1080'} | Set-Content $destination_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also place your script in a file and run it as such:

```
powershell.exe -file My\FilePath.ps1
```

Here is the help section from the powershell executable:

> PowerShell -Help
>
> -File
>
> Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
>      functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
>      current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
>      File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
>      typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
>      as the script file path followed by the script parameters.

Comment: Hi @Jordan, I don't want to be rude, there shouldn't be additional files. Just one bat to rule them all.